# Clone HTML Element including Its Associated Handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

Can we copy / clone an HTML section including *all* the event handlers attached to it?

To simplify the concept, assume I have a `<div>` which triggers `alert()` upon mouse click. I'd like to duplicate that `<div>` and also the handler associated with it; thus, upon click, the duplicated `<div>` also should trigger an alert. I could copy alright but the handlers don't seem to be duplicated correctly. Here's the [**jsFiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/KHbuh/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.clone(true)` instead of `.clone()`.

---

```
$(function() {
    $(".clickme").click(function() { alert("I am clicked!"); });

    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#clickme-1").clone(true).attr("id", "").appendTo("#container");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KHbuh/1/

---

This clones all associated jQuery data as well, including handlers.

Answer (score 5):

Just provide `true` within `.clone()` argument, as mentioned within documentation:

> ***.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )***
>
> **withDataAndEventsA** Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is `false`. *In jQuery 1.5.0 the default value was incorrectly `true`; it was changed back to `false` in 1.5.1 and up.
>
> **deepWithDataAndEventsA** Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to false).

See the results: http://jsfiddle.net/FdugW/

The code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $(".clickme").click(function() { alert("I am clicked!"); });

    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#clickme-1").clone(true).attr("id", "").appendTo("#container");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('div').clone(true).appendTo(document.body);
```